# Open a new page with div contents

Tags: javascript, html

I have some hidden divs in a HTML page with specific IDs:

```
<div id='log1' style='visibility: hidden;display: none;'>content</div>
<div id='log2' style='visibility: hidden;display: none;'>content</div>
```

And then some links:

```
<a href='?' target='_blank'>Log 1</a>
<a href='?' target='_blank'>Log 2</a>
```

I want the browser to open a new page / tab (or even a popup but this might be bad if the user has popup blockers) with the contents of the corresponding div.

I know I could do some Javascript to create a floating div and show the data in the same page, but I'd like to avoid that. Moreover, if there is a way of doing what I ask without JS (which I doubt) even better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do a popup based on hidden divs in your HTML without using JavaScript, no. There's a CSS trick where if you put the divs far off the page and give them an ID, then link to that as an anchor, the browser will scroll it into view.

On the JavaScript side, it's fairly straightforward. First, add a `data-log` attribute to them to tell us what log we should show, then:

```
var links = document.querySelectorAll("...some selectors for your links...");
Array.prototype.forEach.call(links, function(link) {
    link.onclick = function() {
        var log = document.getElementById(this.getAttribute("data-log"));
        var wnd = window.open("", "_blank");
        wnd.document.write(
            "<!doctype html>" +
            "<html><head>" +
            "<meta charset='appropriate charset here'>" +
            "<title>Title here</title>" +
            "</head><body>" +
            "<div>" + log.innerHTML + "</div>" +
            "</body></html>"
        );
        wnd.document.close();
        return false; // Prevents the default action of following the link
    };
});
```

Note the `window.open` must be done *within* the click handler; most popup blockers will allow the popup if it's in *direct* response to a user action.

`window.open` returns a reference to the window, and then we can write to its document.

---

(I don't normally use `onclick` handlers, but you didn't mention using any library and there's still a lot of IE8 out there. Using `onclick` lets us use `return false` to prevent the default; [details in this small article](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2011/11/story-on-return-false.html) on my anemic little blog.)

Comment: I liked the anchor idea! Didn't thought of it. This is for a testing environment with "heavy" linux machines and I preferred not to use any JS, so I'll go with the anchors.

Answer (score 0):

```
var newWindow = window.open("about:blank", "", "_blank");
newWindow.document.write(html);
```

In this case you should be doing this using javascript within a call back it could be on page load or on button click or something else

Comment: No explanation, no context, no indication of when you'd do this, or how you'd know what HTML to put there...